# Adapative Cards and Microsoft Teams: find and display user name and vote

Tags: microsoft-teams, survey, user-profile, adaptive-cards

I'm a long time follower, first time poster! I am logic-oriented but have little experience (mostly Excel VBA) so your help is appreciated.

**Goal**: Automate soliciting of approval of Teams users for a given subject. Approval status of each user should be visible to each user.

- In a Teams group chat, post an adaptive card (or poll) asking for a vote of "approved" or "not approved".[(click for image of card concept)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDP89.jpg)
- Participants of the group chat can select an option such as "approved" and click the "submit" button, which then updates the card to show that person's name with "approved" next to it. In other words, record and display results (name and vote) in the card in the Teams group chat.
- Participants can also use the group chat to have a discussion before voting.

**Problem**: When a user clicks "submit", how can I retrieve that user's name (Teams display name?), like a "me" function or something? At this point the user is already logged into Teams, so I'd expect not to have to authenticate them again. I'm just not sure what expression can be placed in the textbox that will retrieve the user's name.

**What I've tried**:

- I've explored the Approvals feature of Office 365 but it feels more like a solo thing instead of a group that discusses and then votes. Also I doubt my coworkers would be into looking in some other Approvals tab on a regular basis; took long enough to get them to at least use Teams.
- I've tried the Forms route, opening a Teams group chat and clicking Forms to make a quick poll, but that poll has very few settings - I can't make it display the results in the group chat :(
- Tried setting the value of a textbox in the card to *https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/displayname/$value* but got "InvalidAuthenticationToken" error.

I had the whole adaptive card and JSON modeled up to look like my attached image but the browser closed and I lost it, but I don't think it's necessary to show for this question to be answered. 
Please forgive me as a new user - your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You get the user principle name from [Bot Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-context) or [Teams specific context for your Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet)

Comment: Have you looked into @Trinera-MSFT's suggestion?